# Const function in C

Tags: c, function

In the source code of git, I saw the following function definition

```
const char *typename(unsigned int type)
{
    if (type >= ARRAY_SIZE(object_type_strings))
        return NULL;
    return object_type_strings[type];
}
```

I believed that `typename` is a function here, but seems be to a `const` function, which is very confusing to me.

What does this mean and how shall one use this `const` function feature?

link to source cod; 
https://github.com/git/git/blob/7d722536dd86b5fbd0c0434bfcea5588132ee6ad/object.c#L29

Comment: It's a function that returns a `const char *`. (Other than `static`, which is an attribute of the function, `const` qualifies the return type here.)

Comment: You're parsing it wrong - it's just a function that returns a `const char *`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `cdecl`

```
% cdecl
cdecl> explain const char *typename(unsigned int)
declare typename as function (unsigned int) returning pointer to const char
```

It is an useful tool sometimes, but it is quite restricted, for example it said

```
cdecl> explain const char *typename(unsigned int foo);
syntax error
```

But it is very useful when trying to make sense of function pointers:

```
cdecl> declare a as pointer to function (int, double, pointer to const char) 
       returning pointer to const volatile struct foo
const volatile struct foo *(*a)(int , double , const char *)
```

or

```
cdecl> explain const void *(*b[])(int , char (*(*)(char ))(double))
declare b as array of pointer to function (int, pointer to function (char) returning pointer
to function (double) returning char) returning pointer to const void
```